# bluetooth issue with motorola Droid x

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need a small help for the app I am developing.

In short in my app I will be connecting to one device (which was developed by engineering team of the client) through the bluetooth to get the data from that device.

I have used following code for bluetooth connection.

```
BluetoothDevice btDevice = _btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});              
sock = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(btDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));                           
sock.connect();

// m is a Method and sock is BluetoothSocket object.
```

This code is working with all the devices except Motoral Droid x

It is throwing an exception:

> java.io.ioexception : Permission denied.

I tried in all the forums but I could not find a solution for it.

Please help me if any one has the solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @mu is too short - you ever figure this out?

Comment: @c12: I don't know any Android stuff, I just re-tagged it to help the Android people find it.